# Why focus-visible would not work on <a>, when it has a <div> as its child?

Tags: html, css

I am working on keyboard accessibility, and I notice that for `<a>` tag with `<div>` as its child, browser(I am using Brave, which is Chromium) will not show styles I defined with `:focus-visible`, which I guess that pseudo state is not applied to the element. Why is that?

```css
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}

a:focus-visible {
  outline: 2px solid #d3af7a;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://example.com">
  this can be focused and trigger styles in :focus-visible
</a>

<a href="https://example.com">
  <div>
    this can be focused but cannot trigger styles in :focus-visible
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: It seems to work, but due to the display type of div, it isn't showing correctly. Try updating the display type for the `a` to `display: inline-block` and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The style *does* apply to the `a` element but the `div` element is displayed outside the `a` because `div` has display `block` by default while `a` has `inline` display.

You can fix this by matching the display styles of the parent and child elements. This can be done by either (**1**) using an inline element like `span` instead of `div` (or changing the `display` property on the `div` with CSS), or (**2**) setting the `display` property of the `a` to `block` or `inline-block`. The right choice depends on what you want the `display` property of the link to be.

**Example 1: Using `span` instead of `div`:**

```css
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}

a:focus-visible {
  outline: 2px solid #d3af7a;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://example.com">
  this can be focused and trigger styles in :focus-visible
</a>

<a href="https://example.com">
  <span>
    this can be focused but cannot trigger styles in :focus-visible
  </span>
</a>
```

**Example 2: Changing the `display` property of the `a` element:**

```css
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}

a:focus-visible {
  outline: 2px solid #d3af7a;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block; /* or block */
}
```

```html
<a href="https://example.com">
  this can be focused and trigger styles in :focus-visible
</a>

<a href="https://example.com">
  <div>
    this can be focused but cannot trigger styles in :focus-visible
  </div>
</a>
```